# Jquery clash because of -jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, lightbox

My Menu does not seem to function properly on photogallery page :-http://www.vancha.in/Photogallery.aspx

However its seems to function on the home page.

If I remove jquery-1.10.2.min.js  file on photogallery page ,then it functions properly.
I'm using lightbox script.

There is some clash that's happening.

Please Help !

Regards,
Vancha

---

I have tried something like this since now I'm using pretty Photo:-

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">     
     var $jq161 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $jq161(document).ready(function () {
     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();});
</script>
```

Its still not working :(

Comment: it may happen due to different versions of jquery check this http://www.walkswithme.net/jquery-conflict-checking-for-solution

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,Use the library you required

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.4.2.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
   var jq_4 = jQuery.noConflict();
   jq_4(function () { 
       jq_4('#gallery a').lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true }); 
   })
</script>
```

http://interface88.blogspot.in/2012/07/using-multiple-version-of-jquery-on.html

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: what is var jq_4 How are we suppose to use it. I have following script on the page. 

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#gallery a').lightBox({ fixedNavigation: true });
        });
 </script>

Please Help.

Regards,
vancha

Comment: check the edited code , here i am using jquery1.4.2.js place the js you required

Answer (score 0):

I can see that Jquery is referenced multiple times on this URL

http://www.vancha.in/Photogallery.aspx

You may need to fix that.